# Ionic : Hide keyboard smiley icon

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic-keyboard

In app.js I have,

```
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
```

And in my HTML I have ,

```
<ion-footer-bar keyboard-attach class="bar-stable item-input-inset" style="margin-bottom: 50px; height: 60px; background-color: white;">
    <input style="width: 100%;" type="text" placeholder="{{'text_input' | translate}}" ng-model="post.new"/>
</ion-footer-bar>
```

I want to hide the smiley button in android above 5.0 when the keyboard is active.How can i do that? I don't want the user to enter the smiley in the text field.

Answer (score 1):

one simple hack is to change input type of the input field to something else..
I changed input type to url according to my need and it worked.

```
<ion-footer-bar keyboard-attach class="bar-stable item-input-inset" style="margin-bottom: 50px; height: 60px; background-color: white;">
    <input style="width: 100%;" type="url" placeholder="{{'text_input' | translate}}" ng-model="post.new"/>
</ion-footer-bar>
```

hope this helps..

Comment: The type="url" did not worked. Any other suggestions please.